# Carry out itertools.product allowing for a different number of repetitions for different iterables

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-itertools

Let's say I have two iterables `A = 'ab'` and `B = '12'`.

[`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) returns an iterator which will generate the cartesian product of `A` and `B`; e.g.

```
>>> list(itertools.product(A,B)) 
[('a', '1'), ('a', '2'), ('b', '1'), ('b', '2')].
```

The function has an optional keyword argument `repeat`, which can be used to find the cartesian product of an iterable with itself; e.g.

```
>>> list(itertools.product(A,repeat=2))
[('a', 'a'), ('a', 'b'), ('b', 'a'), ('b', 'b')]
```

and is equivalent to `list(itertools.product(A,A))`.

Then using `repeat=2` and both `A` and `B` gives

```
>>> list(itertools.product(A,B,repeat=2))
[('a', '1', 'a', '1'), ('a', '1', 'a', '2'), ('a', '1', 'b', '1'), ('a', '1', 'b', '2'), ('a', '2', 'a', '1'), ('a', '2', 'a', '2'), ('a', '2', 'b', '1'), ('a', '2', 'b', '2'), ('b', '1', 'a', '1'), ('b', '1', 'a', '2'), ('b', '1', 'b', '1'), ('b', '1', 'b', '2'), ('b', '2', 'a', '1'), ('b', '2', 'a', '2'), ('b', '2', 'b', '1'), ('b', '2', 'b', '2')]
```

and is equivalent to `list(itertools.product(A,B,A,B))`.

But now let's say I want to find the cartesian product of `n_A` repetitions of `A` and `n_B` repetitions of `B`, where `n_A` and `n_B` dont have to be the same. How can I do this? It would be nice if `repeat` took the tuple `(n_A, n_B)` and I could write

```
list(itertools.product(A,B,repeat=(n_A,n_B)))
```

e.g.

```
list(itertools.product(A,B,repeat=(2,3))) == list(itertools.product(A,A,B,B,B))
```

but this doesn't appear to be allowed.

Note, rechnically `(A,A,B,B,B)` is a different product to `(A,B,A,B,B)`, however I'll be sorting the outputs anyway so I don't care about the order of input.

Comment: What should `product(A,B,repeat=(2,3))` be equivalent to (without `repeat` argument)?

Comment: Are you referring to the order of the repetitions? I.e. `product(A,A,B,B,B)`, `product(A,B,A,B,B)` or some other order of `A` and `B`? I guess technically this would change the products since they'd be in a different order, however I'll then be sorting the products, so it doesn't really matter.

Comment: That's part of why I asked, yes. The other reason is because Adam's answer does something like `product(A*2,B*3)` instead, producing 2-tuples instead of 5-tuples.

Comment: Since I'm sorting the products (and will this give repeated results) perhaps I'm not looking for the product at all but rather a combination?

Answer (score 2):

Using [`tee`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.tee) to "duplicate" each iterable, then flatten them to a single list of arguments and using * unpacking to pass them to product as individual args

```py
from itertools import product, chain, tee

def myproduct(*iterables, repeat=1):
    if isinstance(repeat, int):
        return product(iterables, repeat)
    assert isinstance(repeat, tuple)
    args = chain(*map(tee, iterables, repeat))
    return product(*args)


A = 'ab'
B = '12'

n_A = 2
n_B = 3


result = list(product(A, A, B, B, B))
result2 = list(myproduct(A, B, repeat=(n_A, n_B)))

print(result == result2)
```

Comment: `len` won't work with all iterables. `chain.from_iterable(tee(iterable, count))` should work for any iterator (and is shorter to boot).

Comment: @chepner neat! tested and edited :)

Comment: Yeah, see Kelly's comment on the question and my edit for clarification. I think using `tee` is the right idea. Something like `product(tee(A,n_A), tee(B,n_B))`, but this gives a list of `tee` objects.

Comment: Bit shorter: `args = chain(*map(tee, iterables, repeat))`

Comment: @KellyBundy Bit shorter but LOT more readable :) Nice learning that map can accept multiple iterables and "zips" them on its own, first time I see it